# How to disable logback ConsoleAppender in Spring Boot

Tags: logback, spring-boot

I am building a command line application using Spring Boot. In such an application, logback console logging is not appropriate. How can I completely disable the console appender, but still have the file appender working with the [default Spring Boot support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging)?

### Update

I have created a feature request for simpler support of this feature here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1612

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add a file called `logback.xml` in `src/main/resources` with content like (copied verbatim except for console part from Spring Boot's source):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>


    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${PID:- } [%t] --- %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n%wex"/>

    <appender name="FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%i</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Note that

```
<property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
```

is needed in order to support setting the log file from Spring Boot's `logging.file` and `logging.path`.

If all you want to do is set some standard log file, you could set place it's path in property above.

**Update (02-04-2015)**

In newer versions of Spring Boot you can easily just include the `base.xml` from Spring Boot and create the following `logback.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**Update (15-09-2017)**

In order to get this working on Spring Boot 1.5.x and 2.0.0.M4 I added a file called `logback-spring.xml` and added it in the `resources` directory.
The file could look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>


    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <property name="FILE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p ${PID:- } [%t] --- %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n"/>

    <appender name="FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%i</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy
                class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: But https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/basic.xml includes `CONSOLE`. That wouldn't appear to work unless I'm missing something

Comment: Thanks. Would that work if I was using `${logging.path}` / `${logging.file}` in my `application.yml`? I am typically setting these in system properties (`-D` flags) when I launch the application.

Comment: I'll get back to you in a minute

Comment: @btiernay A first attempt at using those properties in a properties file was unsuccessful. I'll keep looking

Comment: @btiernay My comment above is wrong. Actually using the property `logging.file` in my `application.properties` produces the correct file output

Comment: I would suggest just doing what is in the shipped [`logback.xml`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/logback.xml) and simply add a root logger which only logs to file (just as @geoand did. Saves you copying the content from the earlier mentioned file.

Comment: @M.Deinum logback.xml not found :(

Comment: In newer versions that has been renamed to `defaults.xml`.

Comment: I am using 1.2.5.Release, adding <appender-ref ref="FILE"> in application specific logback.xml do not seem to work. It still continues to log on console.  Below is the application specific logback.xml `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
</configuration>
`

Comment: @HussainPirosha You should probably create a new question that where you can post all the relevant code and more details regarding your problem

Comment: The updated solution doesn't work for me :(  I had to take all the content of base.xml and redefine the root logger in order to have nothing on console.

Answer (score 12):

Using Spring Boot 1.3.0, I created a file `logback-spring.xml` (in `src/main/resources` with the following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <springProfile name="dev">
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="staging,prod">
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

Additionally, I added the `logging.file` property in `application-staging.properties` and `application-prod.properties` to specify what the file name should be.

This will log to console for `dev` and to file for `staging` or `prod` profiles.

Answer (score 3):

Tested with latest 1.3.1 spring boot release..

place logback.xml under resource folder

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />

    <!-- Send debug messages to a file "application.log" -->
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">

        <file>application.log</file>

        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>application.%i.log</FileNamePattern>
            <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
            <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Also make sure to remove exclusions of spring-boot-starter-logging from "spring-boot-starter" and "spring-boot-starter-web" dependency, if you added exclusions before.

No need of below dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

application.properties

```
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

Comment: Why down vote? This is well tested code on my project and its working fine in prod too....

Answer (score 2):

I tried removing console configuration from logback.xml. But, It was still logging in console. So What I did is, I just removed the appender being added in the logging configuration by springboot. Thereby, we can stop springboot logging in console and separate log file. Add the below lines at the end of your application specific appenders are added. Your custom appender should not match any of these appender names. It worked for me.

```
// get instance of your log4j instance
Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();
logger.removeAppender("CONSOLE"); // stops console logging
logger.removeAppender("LOGFILE"); // stops file logging
```

Comment: I found that you needed: `appLogger.detachAppender("console")` (lowercase letters). However I am not using Spring boot, just a console app

Answer (score 0):

Include `file-appender.xml` and not `console-appender` with the following configuration in `logback-spring.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

You also need to add `logging.file` to your `application.properties`

This is in compliance with what is mentioned on spring boot documentation - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the below to your application.properties

```
logging.level.root=OFF
spring.main.banner-mode=OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `logback-spring.xml` in which you can enable, and disable the console log, and file log based on profile.

I have commented out the console appender for the prod profile and for default (when no profile is active). It will print the logs only in the file. It will print to both console and file for local, dev, etc. profiles.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">

    <!-- include **/appLog*log* in global gitignore file
         to avoid below log files showing up in git -->
    <property name="log.path" value="log"/>
    <property name="log.filename.prefix" value="appLog"/>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />

    <!-- logs folder created in user.dir folder,
         value is printed by calling System.getProperty("user.dir")
         if you want see this property for a running jvm process, then do the following
          - execute command "jps -lm" and identify the pid of the server process
          - execute command "jcmd <SERVER PROCESS PID> VM.system_properties" to see the properties
    -->

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} || [%thread] || %-5level || %logger{36} || %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE-ROLLING" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${log.path}/${log.filename.prefix}.log</file>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${log.path}/archive/year_%d{yyyy, aux}/month_%d{MM, aux}/${log.filename.prefix}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- each archived file, size max 10MB -->
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            <!-- total size of all archive files, if total size > 1GB, it will delete old archived file -->
            <totalSizeCap>1GB</totalSizeCap>
            <!-- 3653 days (10 years) to keep -->
            <maxHistory>3653</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} || [%thread] || %-5level || %logger{36} || %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <springProperty scope="context" name="application_name" source="spring.application.name"/>

    <appender name="jsonConsoleAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>

    <!-- remove log related properties in application.yaml and application-test.yaml files
         of application for below log level setting to be honored -->
    <springProfile name="!(local | dev | test | test_common)">
        <root level="INFO">
<!--        <appender-ref ref="jsonConsoleAppender" />   -->
            <!-- <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" /> -->
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>

    <!-- prod profile specific configuration -->
    <springProfile name="prod | production">
        <root level="WARN">
            <!-- appenders included in the first spring profile tag, if included here,
                 then it will lead to duplicate logs with json format and console format-->
            <!--
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING" />
            -->
        </root>
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="local | dev | test | test_common">
        <root level="DEBUG">
<!--    <root level="TRACE"> -->
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
            <appender-ref ref="FILE-ROLLING" />
        </root>
    </springProfile>

</configuration>
```