# Prevent Spring Boot from printing logs to console

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot for my application and I am using default spring boot logging.

In my `application.properties`, I have added file path for `logging.file`,

```
        logging.file= ${logger_path}
```

and my `pom.xml` contains

```
       <logger_path>/tmp/app.log</logger_path>
```

When I start the application, it prints the logging messages to the file at `/tmp/app.log`, but the problem is it also prints the log messages on the console. I really don't understand why it is printing on console (**though it is printing them to the specified file**) when I have specified a `log file`.

Is there any configuration to prevent spring boot from printing the log messages to console?

Comment: With latest 1.3.1 release [Answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019350/how-to-disable-logback-consoleappender-in-spring-boot/34852737#34852737)

Comment: With latest 1.3.1 release tested here [Answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019350/how-to-disable-logback-consoleappender-in-spring-boot/34852737#34852737)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spring boot comes with build-in `logback` logger, which is configured to print to the console by default.

You need to overwrite the `logback` configuration (providing your own `logback.xml` on the classpath).
This is described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html) -  - section 66.1

How to disable logback logging read [here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#rootElement) -

as you can see you have to provide the value `OFF`...something like:

```
<configuration>
  <include resource="base.xml" />
   .
   .
  <property name="root.level.console" value="OFF" />
</configuration>
```

**Note:** Keep in mind that the general idea here is that the logback configuration coming from spring-boot is minimal. The intention is that you provide your own logback configuration and completely overwrite the existing one - e.g. providing your own logback configuration with only log file-appender configured - this should be your general approach.

Comment: but I specified `logging.file` right? shouldn't it stop printing it to console?

Comment: no. checkout the logback base.xml in spring-boot - find sources on github - you will see two log appenders defined - file and console. The path you supply is passed on to the file-appender - you still have to turn off the console-appender.

Comment: The relevant part of the docs is [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging-file-output) "If you want to write log files **in addition** to the console output you need to set..."

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me :( I had to take all the content of base.xml and redefine the root logger in order to have nothing on console.

Answer (score 7):

Include `file-appender.xml` and not `console-appender` with following configuration in `logback-spring.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
        <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}/}spring.log}"/>
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </root>
    </configuration>
```

You also need to add `logging.file` to your `application.properties`

This is in compliance to what is mentioned in spring boot documentation - http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-logging.html

Comment: And how to achieve this with application.properties?

Answer (score 3):

I tried removing console configuration from logback.xml. But, It was still logging in console. So What I did is, I just removed the appender being added in the logging configuration by springboot. Thereby, we can stop springboot logging in console and separate log file. Add the below lines at the end of your application specific appenders are added. Your custom appender should not match any of these appender names. It worked for me.

```
// get instance of your log4j instance
Logger logger = LogManager.getRootLogger();
logger.removeAppender("CONSOLE"); // stops console logging
logger.removeAppender("LOGFILE"); // stops file logging
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar discussion can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019350/how-to-disable-logback-consoleappender-in-spring-boot).

My logback.xml looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
  <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/file-appender.xml" />

  <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Just in case you still experience an issue: I have read many discussions about that topic and it was not working at all for me. Unfortunately I have made a really stupid mistake when I have created the file logback.xml for the very first time: A space was added at the beginning of the filename. Therefore the file was never used. So just have another look on the filename, add the file in "src/main/resources" and remove any "logging.config" entries from your property files.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with latest 1.3.1 release, with newer releases base.xml has been renamed to defaults.xml

[Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019350/how-to-disable-logback-consoleappender-in-spring-boot/34852737#34852737)