# How to find the location of where a StackTrace is being printed?

Tags: java, spring, logging, stack-trace, printstacktrace

We have some mobile apps that use a Spring REST endpoint. Due to some faulty apps, we see occurrences of `ClientAbortException` on the server. Now the problem is, that this is not logged via the configurable logging mechanism—but apparently just written to console, causing all sorts of problems.

So given the below stacktrace, that doesn't even contain our own code, how do I find out where this exception is printed? I already tried the following:

1. I added a specific error handler for Spring. This works in that the error handler is called—but the stacktrace gets printed nonetheless.

```
  @ExceptionHandler(ClientAbortException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
  public Object exceptionHandler(ClientAbortException exc) {
    return null; //socket is closed, cannot return any response
  }
```

2. I tried setting break-points in the various `Throwable.printStackTrace` methods. None seem to be called.
3. I implemented a custom `PrintStream` via delegate pattern, and set this using `System.setErr(debuggablePrintStream);` and `System.setOut(debuggablePrintStream);`. Again, the various `println` methods don't seem to be called.

So I am running out of options short of using a [Java Agent to manipulate the bytecode](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/03/09/java-bytecode-instrumentation-using-agent-breaking-into-java-application-at-runtime/) of some final classes directly. And then where would I best start?

Here is the obnoxious stack trace that keeps flooding our console:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:309) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:272) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:118) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:523) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.OnCommittedResponseWrapper$SaveContextServletOutputStream.flush(OnCommittedResponseWrapper.java:523) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(FilterOutputStream.java:153) ~[?:?]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.flush(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:1178) ~[jackson-core-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:1008) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar!/:2.11.4]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:452) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.java:104) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:277) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:219) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:428) [spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:75) [spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:141) [spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:80) [spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1320) [spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1131) [spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1077) [spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) [spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) [spring-security-web-5.4.5.jar!/:5.4.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) [spring-boot-actuator-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:764) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:887) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1684) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:113) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:79) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:50) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:466) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.flush(SecureNioChannel.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.write(SecureNioChannel.java:836) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:152) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:717) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:572) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.flush(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:157) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:220) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1195) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:402) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:305) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.43.jar!/:9.0.43]
    ... 96 more
```

For clarification: I don't want to know where it is raised, I want to know where it originates from, i.e. where it is being printed.

Comment: See if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918414/how-to-disable-console-logging-in-spring-boot

Comment: do you explicitly just want to know where the stack trace originated or do you just want to know where in the code the exception was raised?

Comment: Where it was raised I can see in the stacktrace. But why is it printed to console and how do I avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the problematic location after a lot of debugging. Essentially what I did to find the problem was simply:

1. Put a breakpoint where the exception is being raised.
2. Step through the code with the debugger and watch the console until the error is being logged.
3. When the error was logged, put a breakpoint to the last executed statement *before* the error was logged and restart debugging there. Then step into the respective code of the statement and continue with 2.

The culprit is that the exception gets logged deep in the network logic using a different logging framework (JUL), that messed up our logging configuration. Apparently, the [%rException configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.1/manual/layouts.html) doesn't handle exceptions passed via log4j-JUL adapter very well...