# Unable to disable logback logging to console for a spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, spring-logback

I have a Spring boot application where i use Logback. I want it to only log to the file and not the console. I have following properties

```
logging.path=/log/myapp/
logging.pattern.console=
```

i am getting this error when i try to run the app

```
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout("") - Empty or null pattern.
```

Can somebody please help with this

Comment: Duplicate question check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935151/prevent-spring-boot-from-printing-logs-to-console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Spring Boot from printing logs to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935151/prevent-spring-boot-from-printing-logs-to-console)