# How to exclude a specific class for a specific logger with SLF4J

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j

My program has an underlaying system that persist every log in elasticsearch.
I have a class that fetches data online and logs it with slf4j `log.error(data)`.
This allow the underlaying system to persist the log in elasticsearch, but it also floods the console with every fetched data.

I wish to disable the `consoleAppender` just for this specific class.

I've seen other post where people would [disable the `consoleAppender` with logback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019350/how-to-disable-logback-consoleappender-in-spring-boot) or would [exclude all logging from a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270052/how-to-exclude-a-single-class-from-a-log4j-logger-appender), but I couldn't find any information on how to disable *one* logger in *one* class.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to set the logging level for that class. Set it to ERROR, WARN or another level, depending on the level of the messages that are flooding the console. Try modifying the application.properties file by adding something like:

```
logging.level.com.test.MyClass=WARN
```

Comment: It indeed works. Now it seems like I miss something about the logging system in SpringBoot. How is it that when I set `logging.level.com.test.MyClass="OFF"`, the custom logger I register programmatically still catches the log events? Shouldn't this config deactivate *all* logging for `MyClass`?

Comment: You don't need quotes around OFF